# Improve performance or redesign 'greatest-n-per-group' mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance, greatest-n-per-group, filesort

I'm using MySQL5 and I currently have a query that gets me the info I need but I feel like it could be improved in terms of performance.

Here's the query I built (roughly following [this guide](http://murrayhopkins.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/mysql-left-join-on-last-or-first-record-in-the-right-table/)) :

```
SELECT d.*, dc.date_change, dc.cwd, h.name as hub
FROM livedata_dom AS d
      LEFT JOIN ( SELECT dc1.*
        FROM livedata_domcabling as dc1
        LEFT JOIN livedata_domcabling AS dc2
        ON dc1.dom_id = dc2.dom_id AND dc1.date_change < dc2.date_change
        WHERE dc2.dom_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY dc1.date_change desc) AS dc ON (d.id = dc.dom_id)
      LEFT JOIN livedata_hub AS h ON (d.id = dc.dom_id AND dc.hub_id = h.id)
WHERE d.cluster = 'localhost'
GROUP BY d.id;
```

EDIT: Using ORDER BY + GROUP BY to avoid getting multiple dom entries in case 'domcabling' has an entry with null date_change and another one with a date for the same 'dom'.

I feel like I'm killing a mouse with a bazooka. This query takes more than 3 seconds with only about 5k entries in 'livedata_dom' and 'livedata_domcabling'. Also, EXPLAIN tells me that 2 filesorts are used:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | d          | ALL    | NULL                        | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL            |    3 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                        | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL            |    3 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | h          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY                     | 4       | dc.hub_id       |    1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | dc1        | ALL    | NULL                        | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL            |    4 | Using filesort                               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | dc2        | ref    | livedata_domcabling_dc592d9 | livedata_domcabling_dc592d9 | 4       | live.dc1.dom_id |    2 | Using where; Not exists                      |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How could I change this query to make it more efficient?

Using the dummy data (provided below), this is the expected result:

```
+-----+-------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+------+-----------+
| id  | mb_id | prod_id | string | position | name       | cluster   | date_change         | cwd  | hub       |
+-----+-------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+------+-----------+
| 249 | 47    | 47      |     47 |       47 | SuperDOM47 | localhost | NULL                | NULL | NULL      |
| 250 | 48    | 48      |     48 |       48 | SuperDOM48 | localhost | 2014-04-16 05:23:00 | 32A  | megahub01 |
| 251 | 49    | 49      |     49 |       49 | SuperDOM49 | localhost | NULL                | 22B  | megahub01 |
+-----+-------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+------+-----------+
```

Basically I need 1 row for every 'dom' entry, with

1. the 'domcabling' record with the highest date_change

   - if record does not exist, I need null fields
   - ONE entry may have a null date_change field per dom (null datetime field considered older than any other datetime)
2. the name of the 'hub', when a 'domcabling' entry is found, null otherwise

CREATE TABLE + dummy INSERT for the 3 tables:

**livedata_dom** (about 5000 entries)

```
CREATE TABLE `livedata_dom` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mb_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `string` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cluster` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mb_id` (`mb_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `prod_id` (`prod_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `livedata_domgood_string_7bff074107b0e5a0_uniq` (`string`,`position`,`cluster`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5485 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `livedata_dom` VALUES (251,'49','49',49,49,'SuperDOM49','localhost'),(250,'48','48',48,48,'SuperDOM48','localhost'),(249,'47','47',47,47,'SuperDOM47','localhost');
```

**livedata_domcabling** (about 10000 entries and growing slowly)

```
CREATE TABLE `livedata_domcabling` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dom_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cwd` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `date_change` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `livedata_domcabling_dc592d9` (`dom_id`),
  KEY `livedata_domcabling_4366aa6e` (`hub_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `dom_id_refs_id_73e89ce0c50bf0a6` FOREIGN KEY (`dom_id`) REFERENCES `livedata_dom` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `hub_id_refs_id_179c89d8bfd74cdf` FOREIGN KEY (`hub_id`) REFERENCES `livedata_hub` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5397 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `livedata_domcabling` VALUES (1,251,1,'22B',NULL),(2,250,1,'33A',NULL),(6,250,1,'32A','2014-04-16 05:23:00'),(5,250,1,'22B','2013-05-22 00:00:00');
```

**livedata_hub** (about 100 entries)

```
CREATE TABLE `livedata_hub` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin;

INSERT INTO `livedata_hub` VALUES (1,'megahub01');
```

Comment: if nobody answers u by tonight, ill setup a dev area and test it tonight, in the mean time, first thing is * is a no no. putting a * means first sql will do a select table fields, and then populate * with the proper fields. 2-im unsure if you need a inner select just to select from 2 tables where the second table is null. i think u can pull all this off in 1 statment. and if u are going to stick with inner select, DEFENETLY dont do an order by, its pointless, u ordering the innerselect to only join the matching rows in the outer statment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rewriting (tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97637/5)**:

```
SELECT 
    d.*, dc.date_change, dc.cwd, h.name as hub
FROM 
    livedata_dom AS d
  LEFT JOIN 
    livedata_domcabling as dc
        ON dc.id =
           ( SELECT id
             FROM livedata_domcabling AS dcc
             WHERE dcc.dom_id = d.id 
             ORDER BY date_change DESC 
               LIMIT 1
          ) 
  LEFT JOIN 
    livedata_hub AS h 
        ON dc.hub_id = h.id
  WHERE 
     d.cluster = 'localhost' ;
```

And index on `(dom_id, date_change)` would help efficiency.

I'm not sure about the selectivity of `d.cluster = 'localhost'` (how many rows of the `livedata_dom` table match this condiiton?) but adding an index on `(cluster)` might help as well.

Comment: This seems to work way faster than my query and looks like it gives the appropriate result. Will make a few more tests and let you know.

Comment: Yup! Definitely faster! Thank you ypercube! 0.65 s average without adding any indexes. Looks cleaner too.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @rn := 0, @dom_id := 0;
select d.*, dc.date_change, dc.cwd, h.name as hub
from
    livedata_dom d
    left join (
        select
            hub_id, date_change, cwd, dom_id,
            if(@dom_id = dom_id, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as rn,
            @dom_id := dom_id as dm_id
        from
            livedata_domcabling
        order by dom_id, date_change desc
    ) dc on d.id = dc.dom_id
    left join
    livedata_hub h on h.id = dc.hub_id
where rn = 1 or rn is null
order by dom_id
```

The data you posted does not have the dom_id 249. And the #250 has one null date so it comes first. So your result does not reflect what I understand form your question.

Comment: The dom with id 249 is in the dummy livedata_dom insert I posted but there is no entry in livedata_domcabling with dom_id. I want the query result to show null values for the requested columns in that particular case, like described in the sample query output.

In the case of 250, I want the most recent livedata_domcabling info, which is date_change:2014-04-16 05:23:00, cwd:32A, and its associated hub name.

The main question is: how can I improve/redesign the (working but slow) query that I have? I'll give a try to your query but I must admit I don't understand the syntax (beginner in mysql)

Comment: @Michael Ok. I think I got it now. Edited.

Comment: Just tried it, and the query you provided is fast but does not give the expected result. As you were saying, it does not list 249, and the date/cwd for 250 are not the ones I need.

Comment: @Michael Did you try the new one I just edited? It shows the same result as you posted.

Comment: Seems to give the right result, but now it takes about twice the time as the one I have on the production machine (6 sec instead of 3). Thanks for trying though.